# Octave 3D mesh, data from file

Tags: plot, 3d, octave, mesh

I have a big file with 3 columns: density, dimension, value.
example:

```
10 0.3 200  
10 0.4 300  
20 0.3 250  
20 0.4 320
```

I am trying to draw a 3d plot - mesh with `mesh()` function in octave, like this:

```
data = load ("file.txt");   
mesh(data(:,1), data (:,2), data (:,3));
```

Problem I have is , I always get error:

> rows (z) must be the same as length (y), columns (z) must be the same as length (x).

It worked with function `plot3()`, but I would like a mesh kind of plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mesh(X,Y,Z)` is expecting your `X` and `Y` matrices to be generated using `X = meshgrid(x)` and `Y = meshgrid(y)` where `x` and `y` only contain unique points. Your data basically already defines the meshgrid, but it is difficult to get it out.

I suggest using `reshape` as:

```
X = reshape(data(:,1),m,n);
Y = reshape(data(:,2),m,n);    % might be reshape(data(:,2),n,m)
Z = reshape(data(:,3),m,n);
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```

In this case the assumption is that you have `m` unique values in `Y`, and `n` unique values in `X`. You may have to transpose these in your call to mesh as `mesh(X',Y',Z)` or something like that.

Comment: Yes reshape() is the answer, I already managed that but thanks.